# Bluetooth not working in ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: bluetooth

Bluetooth is not working in ubuntu 16.04 in the system settings it is showing no bluetooth adapters found.

$ hciconfig hci0 status

Can't get device info: No such device

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 4-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 2-port SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
```

what is the probable problem ?

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

$ rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8723]
Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723AE PCIe Wireless 
Network Adapter [10ec:0726]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8723ae
Kernel modules: rtl8723ae
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. 
RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5289] (rev 01)
```

Comment: What is the vendor and model number of the bluetooth adapter? (lsusb or lspci)

Comment: please [edit] the output of `rfkill list` into your post. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the output of lspci and lsusb and rfkill list. please see to it and help me out.

Comment: I don't see any bluetooth adapters. Why do you think you have one?

Comment: i switched form windows to ubuntu and bluetooth was working fine in windows so i guess i have one.